# How to properly iterate through an array of rows from a CSV file, after the array has been created?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, valueerror

Very sorry if this was answered before but I searched StackOverflow and could not find a clear solution that solved the problem.

I have a CSV file called “myFile.csv”

- The file is comma (“,”) delimited
- The first row contains the column header, while all subsequent rows are data rows.

I open and read the CSV file, assigning each row to an array called “myArray” that is intended to be used later, for different things…

```
with open("..\dirX\myFile.csv", 'rb') as fileHandle:
    myArray = []
    for row in csv.reader(fileHandle, delimiter=','):
        myArray.append(row)
```

I can successfully print individual rows from the array…

```
print myArray[0]    # Works fine!  Prints header row.
print myArray[1]    # Works fine!  Prints first data row.
```

However, when I try to loop through the array created from the CSV file in order to extract each row, I get a failure.  The for loop code looks as follows...

```
for idx, row in myArray:  # <--- This where the error message points to
    print 'Index = ' + str(idx)
    print row
```

The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File “myScript.py”, line 155, in (module)
        For idx, row in myArray:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

**My Question:** Exactly why does this happen and what is the best way to correct this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lists don't behave differently than any other sequence wrt/ iterations: you only get the items, not the indices (just like when iterating over the `csv.reader` you only got rows, not indices).

If you want to have both indices and items, you can use `enumerate()`:

```
for index, item in enumerate(somelist):
    print("item at {} is {}".format(index, item))
```

Update:

> Because it's enumerated, isn't "item" immutable? What if I want to change it's data, later (e.g. replace text strings)

Iteration doesn't make anything more or less mutable. Either an object is mutable (and mutating it in the `for` loop body works just the same as outside a loop) or it isn't, period.

It seems you are confused by the difference between mutating and rebinding. Here's an example with a list of mutable objects:

```
>>> data = [dict(a=i) for i in xrange(3)]
>>> data
[{'a': 0}, {'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]
>>> for item in data:
...     item["b"] = item["a"] + 42
... 
>>> data
[{'a': 0, 'b': 42}, {'a': 1, 'b': 43}, {'a': 2, 'b': 44}]
```

As you can see the items are perfectly mutable..

Now you can't do this with a list of immutable objects, not because of the `for` loop (wheter you use `enunerate` or not is irrelevant here) but because immutable object are, well, immutable. Let's first check this outside a `for` loop:

```
>>> s = "foo 1"
>>> s.replace("1", "2")
'foo 2'
>>> s
'foo 1'
```

As you can see, `str.replace()` returns a new string and leave the original unchanged (of course - strings are immutable). If you want `s` to become "foo 2", you have to *rebind* `s` to make it point to *another* string:

```
>>> s
'foo 1'
>>> id(s)
139792880514032
>>> s = s.replace("1", "2")
>>> s
'foo 2'
>>> id(s)
139792880474080
```

Note that rebinding a variable does NOT affect other variables pointing to the same object:

```
>>> s1 = "aaa"
>>> id(s1)
139792880524584
>>> s2 = "bbb"
>>> id(s2)
139792880522104
>>> s1 = "aaa"
>>> s1
'aaa'
>>> id(s1)
139792880524584
>>> s2 = s1
>>> s2
'aaa'
>>> id(s2)
139792880524584
>>> s2 is s1
True
>>> # now let's rebind s1:    
>>> s1 = "bbb"
>>> s1
'bbb'
>>> id(s1)
139792880522104
>>> s2
'aaa'
>>> id(s2)
139792880524584
>>> s2 is s1
False
>>>
```

So rebinding the iteration variable (`item` in our above snippets) technically works (this variable IS rebound) but this won't affect the list or whatever you are iterating above (just like rebinding `s1` doesn't impact `s2`):

```
>>> data = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
>>> for item in data:
...     print "item before : {}".format(item)
...     item = 42
...     print "item after : {}".format(item)
...     print "data : {}".format(data)
... 
item before : aaa
item after : 42
data : ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
item before : bbb
item after : 42
data : ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
item before : ccc
item after : 42
data : ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

So if you have a list of strings and want to update the list in place, you have to mutate the list itself - which requires having the matching indexes too, which you get using `enumerate`:

```
>>> data = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
>>> for index, item in enumerate(data):
...     data[index] = item.upper()
... 
>>> data
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']
```

Notice that here we are not rebinding the iteration variable but mutating the `data` list itself. It works just the same as without a `for` loop:

```
>>> data = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
>>> item = data[0]
>>> item
'aaa'
>>> item = "AAA"
>>> item
'AAA'
>>> data
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

versus:

```
>>> data = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
>>> data[0] = "AAA"
>>> data
['AAA', 'bbb', 'ccc']
>>>
```

Comment: Because it's enumerated, isn't "item" immutable?  What if I want to change it's data, later (e.g. replace text strings)?

Comment: @InformationTechnology: try the solution offered and see if it makes `item` immutable.  What was the result of the experiment?

Comment: Awesome explanation.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

the error you had means there are more variable name than actual values.

example:

```
lst = [1,2]
a,b = lst # <-- this is ok

a,b,c = lst # error
```

so if you need idx, you can try to use enumerate, thus every iteration will produce two values

```
for idx, row in enumerate(myArray): 
    print 'Index = ' + str(idx)
    print row
```

in case you want to change element

```
res = []
for idx, row in enumerate(myArray): 
  print 'Index = ' + str(idx)
  print row
  #do change
  res.append(changed_row)
```

Comment: Doesn't enumerating the row make it totally immutable/unchangeable?  How would I be able to change values in the row, later?  For example, what if I wanted to replace strings in the row, later?

Comment: @InformationTechnology https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate here is document. it does not change anything.

Comment: @InformationTechnology btw, if you want to change the elements during iteration, you'd better to create another list

Comment: @galaxyan nothing prevents you from mutating a list in place. What you usually want to avoid is adding to/removing from a sequence while you iterate over this same sequence as it messes up the iterator...